# vuex doesn't recognize the mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

This is my vuex root store.

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    account: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    set_account(state,payload) {
      console.log("I AM INSIDE MUTATIONS", )
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setAccount({
      commit
    }, payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit(set_account, payload)
        resolve()
      })
    }
  },
  plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin],
  modules: {
    auth,
    update
  }
});
```

Here after the set account action I commit `set_account` mutation. But it says,

> set_account is not defined

Why could this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `commit()` with **type**, the first argument, being a string equal to `'set_account'`, the name of the respective action function name:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    account: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    set_account(state,payload) {
      console.log("I AM INSIDE MUTATIONS", )
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setAccount({
      commit
    }, payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('set_account', payload)
        resolve()
      })
    }
  },
  plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin],
  modules: {
    auth,
    update
  }
});
```

From the Vuex [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#commit) for commit:

> commit(type: string, payload?: any, options?: Object)

`type`, the first argument should be a string, which in this case would need to match the function name of `set_account`. Without it being a string, it's attempting to evaluate the expression `set_account` which is effectively undefined in the current execution context.

Hopefully that helps!